# Proving the fundamental theorem of calculus using an epsilon-delta limit approach

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Is it legitimate to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC) using an epsilon-delta limit approach?
I've been reading this set of notes https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/Math_1A/lectures/fundamental.pdf which provides a compelling argument, but I'm not entirely sure (I guess as I'm so used to seeing it proven using the extreme value theorem, or similar).

Comment: Just choose the proof you like most. Here's one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877907/is-this-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-correct

Comment: so is the one I linked to valid then? (sorry to be a pain, but I quite like it, so if it is correct that'd be great)

Comment: You have no idea of the can of worms you are opening up with questions like this.

Comment: Oh dear, is it a contentious subject then?!

Comment: Another way would to use the grunwald definition of the $n$th differintegral and the sum form of a definite integral to prove the FTC.